# Calculated angle is stuck in the range +/- pi/2

Tags: objective-c, kobold2d, angle, radians

I'm trying to make virtual joystick control for an iPhone game I am making, and to do so I was getting the angle between the players touch, and the center of the joystick, but when I get the angle, it only goes up to 1.57 radians, and then becomes negative, only to go down to -1.57 and then increase back to 1.57. This causes my joystick to jump to the other side once the angle switches from positive to negative.

This is my method to calculate the angle:

```
-(double) angleOnCircle: (CGPoint) point1: (CGPoint) centerOfCircle
{
    int point1X = point1.x;
    int point1Y = point1.y;
    int centerX = centerOfCircle.x;
    int centerY = centerOfCircle.y;
    double triangleHeight = point1Y - centerY;
    double triangleBase = point1X - centerX;
    double angle = atan(triangleHeight/triangleBase);
    return angle;
}
```

This is where I update the location of the stick:

```
     moveStickAngle = [self angleOnCircle: touchPos : moveStickStartPoint];
    if([self distanceBetweenTwoPoints:touchPos :moveStickStartPoint] < MOVE_STICK_RESTRICTION_RADIUS)
    {
        moveStickCenter = touchPos;
    }
    else
    {
        double newX = MOVE_STICK_START_X + (cos(moveStickAngle) * MOVE_STICK_RESTRICTION_RADIUS);
        double newY = MOVE_STICK_START_Y + (sin(moveStickAngle) * MOVE_STICK_RESTRICTION_RADIUS);
        moveStickCenter = ccp(newX, newY);
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please let me know if you need more information. - Otherwise note that you can "accept" an answer by clicking on the check mark. That marks the problem as solved and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use atan2():

```
double angle = atan2(triangleHeight, triangleBase);
```

atan2(y, x) is exactly meant for this purpose and returns a value between -pi and pi.

Note that atan(y/x) cannot work because it returns the same value for (x, y) and (-x, -y).